# Javascript switch statements with shared cases

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have created a series of switch statements which perform a similar task.

Currently I have something like this...

```
switch(seconds % 10) {
    case 0: bs2 = "zero"; 
    break;
    case 1: bs2 = "one"; 
    break;
    case 2: bs2 = "two"; 
    break;
    case 3: bs2 = "three"; 
    break;
    case 4: bs2 = "four"; 
    break;
    case 5: bs2 = "five"; 
    break;
    case 6: bs2 = "six"; 
    break;
    case 7: bs2 = "seven"; 
    break;
    case 8: bs2 = "eight"; 
    break;
    case 9: bs2 = "nine"; 
}
document.getElementById("s2").className = bs2;
```

This is followed up another very similar switch statement such as...

```
switch(minutes % 10) {
    case 0: bm2 = "zero"; 
    break;
    case 1: bm2 = "one"; 
    break;
    case 2: bm2 = "two"; 
    break;
    case 3: bm2 = "three"; 
    break;
    case 4: bm2 = "four"; 
    break;
    case 5: bm2 = "five"; 
    break;
    case 6: bm2 = "six"; 
    break;
    case 7: bm2 = "seven"; 
    break;
    case 8: bm2 = "eight"; 
    break;
    case 9: bm2 = "nine"; 
}
document.getElementById("m2").className = bm2;
```

This sort of thing carries on further, but I'm sure you get the idea. It works, but as you can see in both statements the only differences are the expressions and the className that the result is being passed to. It strikes me that there must be a more efficient way of doing the same thing. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by creating a function like following

```js
function getFigure(t) {
var value;
switch(t % 10) {
    case 0: value = "zero"; 
    break;
    case 1: value = "one"; 
    break;
    case 2: value = "two"; 
    break;
    case 3: value = "three"; 
    break;
    case 4: value = "four"; 
    break;
    case 5: value = "five"; 
    break;
    case 6: value = "six"; 
    break;
    case 7: value = "seven"; 
    break;
    case 8: value = "eight"; 
    break;
    case 9: value = "nine"; 
}
return value;
}
var seconds = 8;
var bm = getFigure(seconds);
console.log(bm);
```

Or you can further maintain an array with values and get the value like following

```js
let arr = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"];
let seconds = 9;
let minutes = 2;
document.getElementById("s2").className = arr[seconds % 10];
document.getElementById("m2").className = arr[minutes % 10];
```

```css
.nine {
  color: red;
}
.two {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="s2">Seconds</div>
<div id="m2">Minutes</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil Aggarwal The first example worked a treat. I had to remove the line 'var seconds = 8;' as that was already declared as a variable. The second example looked ideal, but I couldn't get it working sadly.

Comment: @UntitledGraphic - Glad to help you :) What error are you facing using the second example? Just make sure that the `var arr` is accessible at the place you are trying to use it.

Comment: I take back my previous comment. It do have it working. I was getting an error 'Duplicate declaration "..."', but removing the lines 'let minutes = 9' and let seconds = 2' resolve that. Not sure why that din't work the first time around when I tried it, but it is all good now.

Comment: @UntitledGraphic - Glad you were able to resolve your issue